# save web scraped data to a txt file

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping

I am trying to save data that I have already scraped from the Yew York times web page, to a txt file.

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


# URL
html_page = 'https://www.nytimes.com/'

page = urllib.request.urlopen(html_page)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")

title_box = soup.findAll("h2", class_= "css-bzeb53 esl82me2")
print(title_box)

# Extract titles from list 
titles = []
for occurence in title_box:
    titles.append(occurence.text.strip())

print(titles)
```

works fine up to this point but i cant manage to create/save to data to a txt file.

```
# Save the Headlines
filename = '/home/stephan/Documents/NYHeads.txt'
with open(filename, 'w') as file_object:
    file_object.write(titles)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is when you are trying to write to file, it has to be a string. In your program `titles` is a list. You need to convert `titles` to string. This should work:

```
filename = '/home/stephan/Documents/NYHeads.txt'
with open(filename, 'w') as file_object:
    file_object.write(str(titles))
```